# A local identity or service provider must be configured (SAML Error )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm getting an Exception **A local identity or service provider must be configured**, when calling SAML2.0 API  **InitiateSSO(HttpResponseBase** httpResponse, **string** relayState, **string** partnerIdP **)**, although I have registerd my machine(PC) into **Server 2012R2 Datacenter** and also created **Relying Party Trust** in ADFS. I don't understand why it's occurring.

SAML.Config [SAML.Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbTcP.png)

Web.Config [Web.Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmzwD.png)

MVC Action Error Message [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPDcz.png)

Relying Party Trust [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziwUE.png)

Relying Party Trust [Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fywvP.png)

Relying Party Trust [EndPoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVuAk.png)

Relying Party Trust [Encryptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYwfi.png)

Fedration Metadata [EntityID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo6ck.png)

so what's wrong or missing in my configuration ?

why I'm getting the exception "A local identity or service provider must be configured'" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you have added the relying party.

Kindly check whether you were able to access the IDP initiated page is working or not by accessing it. If it is not working you need to check the configuration of the ADFS.

Need to check Federation Services DNS name
Service Account or Group Managed Service Account (gMSA)
Domain Admin Permissions.

If you were able to access the IDP initiated page,

The  configuration must match with the relying party configuration in ADFS. If you supplied the IdP with your SAML metadata, the  Name matches the entityID in your metadata. This corresponds to the relying party identifier in ADFS.

If your application is acting as the service provider you need a  entry which includes configuration information about your local service provider. You also need a  entry for each partner identity provider website.

The  entry is applicable if your site were the identity provider rather than the service provider. Your would then have an  and  entries .

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. My application is acting as Service Provider so I was creating the <PartnerServiceProvider> tag rather than <ServiceProvider> in my SAML.Config file. The exception had gone as I changed tag from <PartnerServiceProvider> to <ServiceProvider> and configure <ServiceProvider> tag correspond to Relying Party Trust configuration